# Beginning Android programming - Build your first app

Tags: android, kotlin

After just installing the latest Android Studio (3.0.1) I started with the **Build Your First App guide**. I'm using `Kotlin` as it seems to be the suggested way to go. I managed to run the first Hello World app on my tablet. Then, continuing with the example at
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#kotlin

I got to the point where it instructs "In the Attributes window, locate the onClick property and select sendMessage [MainActivity] from the drop-down list."
The problem is, there is nothing in the drop-down list.

I tried typing `sendMessage` manually in the onClick property of the button, but then the app crashes when I push the button. Also tried `sendMessage()` , `sendMessage(this)` and `sendMessage [MainActivity]` but all of them crash the app. If I remove it, pushing the button does - quite expectedly - nothing, but does not crash either... Also tried adding the property into the **.xml** as instructed in another reply, but no help.

So what is the correct way to call the `sendMessage` function? Which `View object` (?) should I give it and how?

My `MainActivity` looks like this:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText

const val EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    fun sendMessage(view: View) {
        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        val message = editText.text.toString()
        val intent = Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
        }
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

and the DisplayMessageActivity:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView

class DisplayMessageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message)
    }

    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    val message = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).apply {
        text = message
    }
}
```

And I'll raise with the whole stack:

```
03-13 10:19:50.620 20646-20646/com.example.myfirstapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 20646
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2488)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity.<init>(DisplayMessageActivity.kt:15)
                                                                            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1072)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2478)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: please add the stacktrace. This can be helpful in identifying the issue.

Comment: You will find the stacktrace in Logcat https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: Yes, of course, the trace... I think this is actually enough:  
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference    So the problem is that I need to give it a View object?

Answer (score 0):

Your sendMessage method is right.

Typing "sendMessage" in the onClick field(the method name) is enough.

Or in the xml, add

> android:onClick="sendMessage"

to the button attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can add `android:onClick="sendMessage"` or add `setOnClickListener` in your `MainActivity`.

`YourButtonID.setOnClickListener { v ->
       sendMessage(v)
    }`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues.

#### 1. The ["there is nothing in the drop-down list"](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#RespondToButton)

It's 2022 and I faced the same issue. To solve it, I did nothing, just took a break, when I got back the `sendMessage` shows up in the drop-down list. I guess it's the IDE. You can try ctrl-S in the `MainActivity` or restart the IDE.

#### 2. Misplaced when copy-pasting [this code](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#DisplayMessage) which results in the above stacktrace

From [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#DisplayMessage):

> In `DisplayMessageActivity`, add the following code **to the** `onCreate()` method:

**"to the"** means **inside**:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message)
    
    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    val message = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).apply {
        text = message
    }
}
```

If we put the code outside of the `onCreate()` method, the app will crash after we tap the button like OP mentioned.